# Where is the code for RDTSC handler in QEMU source code?

Tags: qemu, rdtsc

I am working on an application which requires me to make some changes with the part of the QEMU source code which deals with RDTSC calls. However, I am not able to locate the same in the huge source code.

Answer (score 3):

Key portion is here:

target-i386/translate.c

```
6850     case 0x131: /* rdtsc */
6851         if (s->cc_op != CC_OP_DYNAMIC)
6852             gen_op_set_cc_op(s->cc_op);
6853         gen_jmp_im(pc_start - s->cs_base);
6854         if (use_icount)
6855             gen_io_start();
6856         gen_helper_rdtsc();
6857         if (use_icount) {
6858             gen_io_end();
6859             gen_jmp(s, s->pc - s->cs_base);
6860         }
6861         break;
```

For general understanding of qemu code related to code translation, this answer is good:

[Qemu code translation main execution loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675226/qemu-code-flow-instruction-cache-and-tcg/21000294#21000294)