# Can I examine Qemu tcg ir code? If so how?

Tags: qemu

I am trying to analyse QEMU tcg IR code

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675226/qemu-code-flow-instruction-cache-and-tcg) post which discusses QEMU code flow. According to the diagram, the translation occurs at target-xxx/translate.c and that's where QEMU translates code from source (or front end) to TCG IR. Then further at tcg/xxx/tcg-target.c.

This process can be summarize as follows (at least according to my understanding) -
Say, we have `x86` as a front-end and `powerpc (ppc64abi32)` as a back-end, then -

`x86` --> `TCG IR` --> `ppc64abi32`

I want to analyse this `TCG IR` code. Is there any way we can generate this code (This may not be relevant, but for eg. we can generate LLVM IR code using a flag -S with clang)?

I did some research myself and found `struct TranslationBlock` (in the file /include/exec/exec-all.h) which has something to do with the tcg IR code (So, I tried to print some struct variables, but I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction). I also read the tiny code generator [readme](https://github.com/S2E/libtcg), but could not find the generation related information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the -d option, which enables debug printing of various things. "-d op" traces the TCG ops. You probably also will want to trace the input and output asm with in_asm and out_asm. The -D file option to dump the tracing to a file is also helpful as the tracing is usually quite large.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thanks @peter Maydell